# setting iframe ID via fancybox2 to allow webdriver switchTo()->frame(id)

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fancybox-2

I'm using [fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to create iframes but I can't see a way of setting the ID of the iframe that gets created, which is preventing me from using php-webdriver and selenium to test the contents of the iframe.

Simplified version of the code:

```
<a href="iframe.html" class="various fancybox.iframe">iframe</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox()
});
</script>
```

Which works, but using Chrome's inspector, the iframe was (this time) generated with an ID of
`fancybox-frame1443817733402`, which appears to be random. This means when I try to use php-webdriver to [switch to this frame](http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/WebDriver.html#method_switchTo) (having clicked the link to create the iframe), I can't predict the frame's ID to pass in:

```
$frame_id = 'fancybox-frame1443817733402'; // can't predict this in advance
$driver->switchTo()->frame($frame_id);
```

The iframe is always generated with a class of `fancybox-iframe` but calls to

```
$iframe = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::class("fancybox-iframe"))
```

return nothing.

I've also tried using fancybox2's `afterLoad` callback to try explicitly setting the iframe's ID before trying to switch to the frame by this ID, but that also fails (I think because `current` is an object, not an element?)

```
$(".various").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
        //console.log(current);
        current.attr('id', 'rob');
    }});
```

Is there a way of explicitly setting the iframe's ID so that I can switch to it via selenium/webdriver? Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about setting the frame id here, but you can switch to a frame via xpath (such as //frame):

```
    protected WebElement gotoIframeByXpath(final String iframeXpath) {
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(iframeXpath)).size() > 0) {  // find elements so an exception isn't thrown if not found
            WebElement contentFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath(iframeXpath));
            driver.switchTo().frame(contentFrame);
            return contentFrame;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to find " + iframeXpath);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this set me in the right direction. I've added the working code below, as I'm using PHP

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, following @EGHM's answer above, this is how I did it.

```
// this also works & is a little simpler
//$iframes = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('iframe'));

$iframes = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xPath('//*[starts-with(@id,"fancybox-frame")]'));
$id = $iframes[0]->getAttribute('id');

$driver->switchTo()->frame($id);
echo $driver->getPageSource();
```